# limit of a function as $x$ goes to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this homework question where I have to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}
\frac{\tan(x)−\sin(x)}{x − \sin (x)}$

I realise that when I put in $0$ there is a divison by $0$ problem.

I've tried rewriting the equation by spliting the numerator into two seperate pieces and then evaluate but I'm unsure how I go about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{x-\sin x}=\dfrac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^3\cos x}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{x-\sin x}$$

Use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) for the last part.

$$\dfrac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^3\cos x}=\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^3\cdot\dfrac1{\cos x(1+\cos x)}$$